# Ember.js - Rendering Template with nested resources and template overriding

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My code:  http://jsbin.com/axaqix/20/edit

My router:

```
    WebApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('sites', { path: '/' } , function() {
        this.resource('site', { path: '/sites/:site_id'} ,  function() {
            this.resource('posts', { path: 'posts' });

        });

        this.route('new', {path: 'new'});

    });

});
```

My templates:

```
<!--Main Page-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sites">
<ul>
    {{#each site in controller}}
    <li>
        {{#linkTo 'site' site}} {{site.siteName}} {{/linkTo}}<br>
        {{#linkTo 'posts' site}} go to posts {{/linkTo}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}

</ul>
{{#linkTo 'sites.new'}} ADD NEW WEBSITE {{/linkTo}}

{{outlet}}
```

```
<!--Displays site details-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="site">
   <p>Site Details</p>
    Name: {{siteName}} <br>
    Secret Key:{{secretKey}} <br>
    Public Key:{{publicKey}} <br>

</script>


<!--Inseting new WEBSITE template-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sites/new">
    <p>Add New WEBSITE</p>
    <div>
        {{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Insert new site name"
        valueBinding="newName" action="addSite"}}
    </div>
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
   <p>Damn</p>

 </script>
```

I have two questions:
 1. Why when I press `go to posts` line it is not rendering `posts` template? Instead it is rendering
    `site` template.

1. Is it possible to make `posts` template override `sites` template?

Note: There are two templates `site` and `sites`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Why when I press go to posts line it is not rendering posts template? Instead it is rendering site template.

You are rendering the posts route as a childRoute of site route. So when you transition to posts,the transition will be like "sites.site.posts" . Hence parent template gets rendered first followed by the child.

> 1. Is it possible to make posts template override sites template?

Yeah you can name your outlet in the sites template as `{{outlet test}}`

and render the site and posts template into it as

```
WebApp.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('posts',{
      into: 'sites',
      outlet: 'test'
    });
    }
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frvJZ/9/)

**Updated**

There is even no need to name your outlets. You can simply render the site and posts template into the sites template as

```
WebApp.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render('posts',{into: 'sites'});
 }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frvJZ/13/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that didn't what I meant in second question. I want to override `sites` template, the template which displays the list. so the word damn will b e displayed below TITLE

Comment: Just render your posts template into application as   this.render('posts',{into: 'application'});